# How to make two arrays have the same dimensions?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I have this part of a for loop:

```
a1.append((x[t] - 2 * x[t - 1] + x[t-2]) / ((t + 1) - (t)) ** 2)

a2.append((y[t] - 2 * y[t - 1] + y[t-2]) / ((t + 1) - (t)) ** 2)

a3.append((z[t] - 2 * z[t - 1] + z[t-2]) / ((t + 1) - (t)) ** 2)
```

To explain further - I am iterating through a list that has 160 values. Yet when I try to plot it placing the a1, a2 and a3 components on the y axis and time(dimension also 160) on the x axis, I am getting the error "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (160,) and (157,)". Any tips on how to fix it? Sorry in advance if the solution is very obvious, its the end of the semester and my brain is mush

Comment: Get the shapes of the arrays you're trying to plot. One of them only has 157 values (is it the time one?). I don't think we can say where the missing values are without seeing more of your code - if that's all within your for loop, then the arrays should come out all the same length.

Comment: Problem would see to lie within your loop. Use `len(a1)` etc after the loop forms the arrays to confirm size if it isn't obvious.